# Httprequest() no funciona con PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu-server

Estoy tratando de implementar este codigo:

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://api.webscrapingapi.com/v1');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_GET);
$request->setQueryData([
  'api_key' => 'XXXXXX',
]);
try {
  $response = $request->send();
  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

y me genera el siguiente error:
**"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in /www/wwwroot/test.dcompras.pe/scripts/prueba.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /www/wwwroot/test.dcompras.pe/scripts/prueba.php on line 3"**

Tengo un VPS con ubuntu 20.04 y aaPanel instalado, las librerias parecen estar instaladas correctamente, pues en el terminal me aparece:

## root@supershop:~# pecl list
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:

Package   Version State
pecl_http 3.2.3   stable
propro    2.1.0   stable
raphf     2.0.1   stable
root@fanshop:~#

las extensiones .so estan el php.ini:

extension = /www/server/php/74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/raphf.so
extension = /www/server/php/74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/propro.so
extension = /www/server/php/74/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/http.so

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?, que estoy haciendo mal?